# Trying to insert data into database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

So here is my php file that connects to my database "pizza"

```
<?php
//Connect to database
$link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'pizza');
if (!$link) {
    //output this message if connection is unsuccessful
    $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    exit();
}
?>
```

Next is my attempt at trying to submit the data

```
<?php
//Include our file that connects us to Pizza database
include("connect.php");

$userAddress = $_POST["address"];
$userPhone   = $_POST["phoneNo"];

//Insert new data into database
$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (address, email, phone) 
         VALUES ('$userAddress',         '$userEmail', '$userPhone')";

if (mysqli_query($sql)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error ";
}

mysql_query($sql);
?>
```

Can anyone see what is wrong here?

Comment: besides not displaying details of any errors?

Comment: besides mixing `mysql_query($sql);`? yes, you're not passing connection to your query.. Besides your missing HTML form? Nope.

Comment: never output a fixed (USELESS) `error` text, especially when the system can TELL you what's wrong. `... else { mysqli_error($link); }` Plus, you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), so enjoy getting your server pwn3d.

Comment: I have the html form in another file

Comment: Read up on the function http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php being `mysqli_query()` and see what's missing from it ;-) along with a variable being `$userEmail`.

Comment: all these comments up there ^^^ "explained" what's wrong with your code. In a certain way of course ;-) *"You're welcome"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
if (mysqli_query($sql)) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
}
```

With this:

```
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
 }
```

Comment: *why* should they do that? you've missed a few things too.

Comment: @Fred-ii-, the OP stated that their form is in another file. Besides, my answer addresses the query part. OP needs first to get their code working.

Comment: @CianWoods, if the answer solved your problem, try to mark it as the accepted answer, so someone else having the same issue can gain from it.

Comment: This worked for me! Data is now going into my database..can you tell me how you knew this?

Comment: addresses, sure. Doesn't "explain why" they should. Non-informative answers won't attract many visitors and possible upvotes but that's up to you. Edit: Oh, now they're asking how you knew this. *"can you tell me how you knew this?"*

Comment: @CianWoods Just a hunch, but maybe he [read the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)?

Comment: @CianWoods, by reading the PHP documentation on `mysqli_query`. Fred -ii- gave you the link already above. But here it is again: php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I totally get your point. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have instantiated a `mysqli` object, you should use its methods to query your database.

```
$link = new mysqli('127.0.0.1','root','','pizza');
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (address) VALUES ('$userAddress')";
if ($link->query($query)) {
  //do stuff
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php